# Issue creating new variable with mutate R using strsplit

Tags: r, dplyr, strsplit, mutate

I am trying to create new variable using mutate from column. I am using strsplit to perform some string operation to create new variable contents. But it is not working as desired.

```
myDF = data.frame(filename = c("T9719178_Mazda_20230415",
                           "T9719179_Mazda_20230415", 
                           "T9719180_Mazda_20230415", 
                           "T9719001_Tesla_20230415", 
                           "T9719002_Tesla_20230415", 
                           "T9719003_Tesla_20230415"))

myDF%>%
mutate(LotCode = as.factor(strsplit(filename,"_",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]))%>%
mutate(ModelName = as.factor(strsplit(filename,"_",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2]))

Current output 
                    filename                LotCode     ModelName
                    T9719178_Mazda_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
                    T9719179_Mazda_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
                    T9719180_Mazda_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
                    T9719001_Tesla_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
                    T9719002_Tesla_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
                    T9719003_Tesla_20230415 T9719178     Mazda

 Expected output 

             filename       LotCode  ModelName
  T9719178_Mazda_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
  T9719179_Mazda_20230415 T9719179     Mazda
  T9719180_Mazda_20230415 T9719180     Mazda
  T9719001_Tesla_20230415 T9719001     Tesla
  T9719002_Tesla_20230415 T9719002     Tesla
  T9719003_Tesla_20230415 T9719003     Tesla
```

I suppose above should be straight forward but not sure what is wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that for each row in your dataset you are extracting the same (i.e., the first) element of the list returned by `strsplit()`.

To rectify your code, you can use `map()` (or `apply()`) to extract the first and second elements from each element of the list:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myDF %>%
  mutate(LotCode = map(strsplit(filename, "_", fixed = TRUE), 1)) %>%
  mutate(ModelName = map(strsplit(filename, "_", fixed = TRUE), 2))
#>                  filename  LotCode ModelName
#> 1 T9719178_Mazda_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
#> 2 T9719179_Mazda_20230415 T9719179     Mazda
#> 3 T9719180_Mazda_20230415 T9719180     Mazda
#> 4 T9719001_Tesla_20230415 T9719001     Tesla
#> 5 T9719002_Tesla_20230415 T9719002     Tesla
#> 6 T9719003_Tesla_20230415 T9719003     Tesla
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Alternatively, you could use `sep_wider_delim()` instead which has the advantage of returning a vector instead of a list:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myDF |> 
  separate_wider_delim(
    filename,
    delim = "_",
    names = c("filename", "LotCode", "ModelName"),
    cols_remove = FALSE
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   filename                LotCode ModelName
#>   <chr>                   <chr>   <chr>    
#> 1 T9719178_Mazda_20230415 Mazda   20230415 
#> 2 T9719179_Mazda_20230415 Mazda   20230415 
#> 3 T9719180_Mazda_20230415 Mazda   20230415 
#> 4 T9719001_Tesla_20230415 Tesla   20230415 
#> 5 T9719002_Tesla_20230415 Tesla   20230415 
#> 6 T9719003_Tesla_20230415 Tesla   20230415
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
myDF %>%
  separate(filename, into = c('LotCode', 'ModelName'), sep = '_', remove = FALSE)
```

Which gives:

```
                filename  LotCode ModelName
1 T9719178_Mazda_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
2 T9719179_Mazda_20230415 T9719179     Mazda
3 T9719180_Mazda_20230415 T9719180     Mazda
4 T9719001_Tesla_20230415 T9719001     Tesla
5 T9719002_Tesla_20230415 T9719002     Tesla
6 T9719003_Tesla_20230415 T9719003     Tesla
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is with `extract` from `tidyr`:

```
myDF %>%
   extract(filename,
           into = c("LotCode", "ModelName"),
           regex = "(.*)_(.*)_.*", remove = FALSE)
                 filename  LotCode ModelName
1 T9719178_Mazda_20230415 T9719178     Mazda
2 T9719179_Mazda_20230415 T9719179     Mazda
3 T9719180_Mazda_20230415 T9719180     Mazda
4 T9719001_Tesla_20230415 T9719001     Tesla
5 T9719002_Tesla_20230415 T9719002     Tesla
6 T9719003_Tesla_20230415 T9719003     Tesla
```

In the `regex` argument we define those substrings we want to extract as patterns and wrape them in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks deschen, @dufei, Chris. All the solutions worked.